# Why the element that splits out from an array is not a string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

```
$requests = array("add : milk",
"remove: milk",
"add : pickles");
$request_option = "add : remove : checkout : quantity_upd";
$request_option_split = explode(":",$request_option);
// print_r($request_option_split);
function shoppingCart($requests,$option){
  $j = sizeof($requests);
  $basket = array();
  if ($option[1] == 'remove') {
    echo "hahah";
  }else{
    echo "f***";
  }
  for ($i=0 ; $i < $j ; $i++) { 
    $temp = explode(":",$requests[$i]);
    // print_r($temp);

    switch ($option[1]) {
      case $option[0]://add
        $basket[$temp[1]] = 1;
      break;

      case $option[1]://remove
      echo "asdf";
      unset($basket[0]);
      break;

      case $option[3]://quantity_upd
      $basket[$temp[1]] = $basket[$temp[1]] + intval($temp[2]);
      break;

      case $option[2]://checkout.
      $j = sizeof($basket);
      for ($i=0; $i < $j; $i++) { 
        unset($basket[$i]);
      }
      break;

      default:
        echo "hello world";
        break;
    }
  }
  print_r($basket);
}
shoppingCart($requests, $request_option_split);
```

I am trying to split each element from an array, then if the element matches the option, it will execute.  For example, I split out the first element of `$request` array, and `$temp[0]` will be `"add"`. However, when I put the `$temp[0]` into the switch statement, it doesn't equal to the string `"add"`. That is so werid.

I use `gettype` function to check it, every element I got from the `$request` array is string. but they are not equal to `"string"`. I am so confusing. I tried the the `$str = (string)$temp[0]` as well. it still doesn't work. can somebody explain it to me please?

Comment: I think you're `switch`ing on the wrong variable.

Comment: My bad, I just post the code

Comment: "when I put the `$temp[0]` into the switch statement" But that's _not_ what you're doing.  You have `switch ($option[1]) {`

Comment: Please see how to post an [mcve] - with a focus on the _minimal_.